# Looking for the correct spelling of “tsundoku” in Japanese

Tags: translation, meaning

I am not learning nor will I be learning Japanese any time soon so I’ll be glad if you could help me out here. 
I am a designer and I wanted to play with the correct Japanese spelling of this word “tsundoku”. As I understand it means buying and piling unread books instead of reading after buying them.
I am attaching a few photos showing some spellings but I have no way to be sure if they’re right. 
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Comment: They're all spelled the same.  They just spell it out in roman characters, hiragana, and Kanji.

Comment: @ajsmart Yes, now I see they do look the same. It took only one person to point it out, which is pretty neat 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the word in a variety of ways. You've shown several  (積ん読) that combine Kanji (Chinese characters) and hiragana, and in your second example, you can see those alongside the same word spelled out in just hiragana　（つんどく）. Both are correct, as ajsmart said. My autocorrect actually gives it as 積読 (without the hiragana between the characters) - a third option, just to add to the confusion. Welcome to the world of Japanese...

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could even spell it a fourth way 積んどく or a fifth way ツンドク....